# Standard web parts not saving custom titles in multiple languages

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, language, multilingual

I have a SharePoint Online modern team site in english language with german as an alternative language. When I add a standard News web part its default title for an user with english language is "News" and for an user with german language it is "Nachrichten". When an user with english language changes the web part title to "Information", the web part title will be information for both the english and the german user. and vice versa if a german user changes it to "Neuigkeiten" It will display this to both english and german users.

How do I get custom web part titles for each language. I think it should actually work this way, that the title gets only changed for the current language. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: This is default behavior in SharePoint when you enter custom title to your webpart. It will not automatically translate the title based om current language settings..

Comment: I do not want it to translate automatically. I want to have different titles for different languages. But whenever I change the title in one language, it also changes to that for all other languages. I have tried this with "Overwrite Translation" on and off in language settings.